# 2 servers behind single IP using DD-WRT and Dynamic DNS

Tags: ddns

I current have a single server running at home. I use freedns.afraid.org to route the domain name to my current ip.

I wish to setup an additional server on a separate domain. How best to achieve it so:

```
domain1.com -> DDNS -> current ip -> DD-WRT -> server 1
```

and

```
domain2.com -> DDNS -> current ip -> DD-WRT -> server 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this routing/directing can be done within DDWRT without doing something like changing the public port for the second server. Example, if server one is listening on TCP port 80 by default, make the second one listen on TCP 8080. In that regard, having a separate DNS domain name doesn't really matter. You can simply access each server at example.com or example.com:8080

If both servers are web server, another option may be to take advantage of Server Name Indication (SNI). Where you can host both domains on a single server, but have them listen/bound to different DNS domain names. This can be done in most web servers (Apache, IIS, etc) however, if you are using HTTPS SSL sites, you can be limited with IIS unless you are running server 2012 or newer.

The only other thing I could think is some kind of reverse proxy setup in something like Apache. Where it receives a request and pushes it to another server. See: [Reverse Proxy/Gateway](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

(**EDIT**)

If trying to do this with regards to FTP and SSH, you will likely need a more advanced router/firewall setup than DDWRT on a home device (unless there is some kind of optware package that enables this)
You might be able to set this up with one of the dedicated firewall/router setups like smoothwall. Otherwise a commercial device like a sonicwall or cisco should allow you to do the port forward based on the HTTP header in the application data

Comment: reverse proxy looks like the way to go, however I was hoping to achieve this on all ports so I can setup ssh, ftp etc without having to configure each port forward separately and have to remember alternatives ports for the 2nd server. Outside of DDWRT home use, what is the commercial method to achieve the above?

Comment: edited my response to include possible commercial alternatives for your FTP and SSH issues, but honestly, it is probably cheaper to just pay your ISP and upgrade to having two static IPs.